# How to attach onclick event on textboxes?

Tags: javascript, dojo

[image]
Hi,
I want to attach on click event on Text Box with value A in attachment and same with B.
I am using dojo toolkit with the following code:

```
  window.onload = function () {

         dojo.query('.test').onclick(function(){
              alert('test');

            });
};
```

I have a table control having two column name and value both columns contain textboxes.On column name textbox i have added a class with name 'test'.The table rows increase dynamically as shown in attachment.
Now my concern is these textboxes increase dynamically how can i attach event on these textbox.On signle textbox this is working fine but here table rows increase and how can i find particular textbox with same class?
Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

define the function separately.

```
var myFunc = function() {
 alert('test');
};
```

Now, use it, to attach to text boxes (like you have already done)

```
dojo.query('.test').onclick(myFunc);
```

But, while adding new rows, it is your duty to attach this function to the newly added text boxes. You can refer it by the name "myFunc".

Note:-
Running the code piece again - "dojo.query('.test').onclick(myFunc);" will add duplicate handlers for existing textboxes.

Answer (score 0):

If you are adding a large number of handlers *or* if the information on the screen is dynamic, you'll want to look at using delegated event handlers.

With delegation, you are only adding one handler, which is better for memory usage *and* you would be adding the handler to the container, not each specific item, which means that the items themselves can safely change without having to re-attach handlers to them.

For more details, I would point you towards this excellent answer: [What is DOM Event delegation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1687296/what-is-dom-event-delegation)